# Cannot view working sets Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Once upon a time I used Eclipse and I discovered this wonderful thing called **working sets**.

Now I am using **Eclipse Luna** and it looks like I have to relearn all about Working Sets again. Because nothing works like before.

On my journey to relearn all about working sets, some folks said that I should go to **Customize Perspective..** and add the window working command group. I did that.

Then I created three working sets which each contained different projects. It kind of looks like this :

[image]

Now, I thought, this is where the fun begins.

Excitedly, I navigated to the **Window menu** and selected all three working sets.

[image]

Astonishingly nothing happened. I used to be able to see multiple working sets at the same time. What happened?

Comment: This should work. What is actually in those Working Sets? Are you sure they don't include all your projects?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the projects split in to Working Sets in the Project Explorer view you need to open the Project Explorer view menu (the small down arrow at the top right of the view) and select 'Top Level Elements > Working Sets'